# Which 'Content Importer' to use for .TXT files?

Tags: visual-studio, xna

[image]

I imported a plain text file into my XNA game, and I'm not sure which Content Importer AND Content Processor to specify, could anyone point me in the right direction? I don't need to do anything special with the file, it's just plain text.. I didn't think it'd need one since I'm just reading it with a StreamReader, so I would like to avoid converting it to .XNB, if possible.

*Note: In case it matters, I'm using C#. I didn't tag it since it shouldn't matter.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicated something very simple. You don't need to put it in your content project at all. You should bundle it with your actual application and put it in the same directory as your application, or use the `Copy To Output Directory` property on the file after you put it in your regular project (in a `Content` folder, if you really need to).

After that, it's just opening a FileStream of `File.Open` on `"index.txt"`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, just one question: since you can import .PNG textures yourself instead of from Content, are there any disadvantages to not using the content pipeline at all (like performance), and just using PNG textures, etc.?

Comment: @leaf68 You're asking this question too early. Make your game first, then measure what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you import/drag it into the content folder within VS you can reach the file like so:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"Content\filename.txt")
{
}
```

This way you can access the text file easy from within VS and it gets sorted properly within content when you publish your project.